# Property-based test continues to pass when I expect it to fail

Tags: f#, property-based-testing

I'm sure this is trivial. However, the following test will always pass:

```
let transform number =  
    match number % 3, number % 5 with 
    | 0, 0 -> "FizzBuzz" 
    | _, 0 -> "Buzz" 
    | 0, _ -> "Fizz" 
    | _ -> number.ToString()

[<Fact>]
let ``FizzBuzz.transform returns FizzBuzz`` () =
    let fiveAndThrees = Arb.generate<int> |> Gen.map ((*) (3 * 5)) 
                                          |> Arb.fromGen

    Prop.forAll fiveAndThrees <| fun number ->

        let actual = transform number

        let expected = "jbdhjsdhjdsjhsdglsdjlljh"
        expected = actual
```

I've also tried:

```
Check.QuickThrowOnFailure <| (expected = actual)
```

Specifically, why does this test continue to pass when it should obviously fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use *FsCheck.Xunit* and its `[<Property>]` attribute:

```
[<Property(QuietOnSuccess = true)>]
let ``FizzBuzz.transform returns FizzBuzz`` () =
    let fiveAndThrees =
        Arb.generate<int> |> Gen.map ((*) (3 * 5)) |> Arb.fromGen
    Prop.forAll fiveAndThrees <| fun number ->

        let actual = FizzBuzz.transform number

        let expected = "FizzBuzz"
        expected = actual
```

Answer (score 4):

You're creating the property, but never actually checking it. It just sits there, never executed once.

To check the property, you need to pass it to one of the `Check.*` methods:

```
[<Fact>]
let ``FizzBuzz.transform returns FizzBuzz`` () =
    let fiveAndThrees = Arb.generate<int> |> Gen.map ((*) (3 * 5)) 
                                          |> Arb.fromGen

    let myProperty = Prop.forAll fiveAndThrees <| fun number ->

        let actual = transform number

        let expected = "jbdhjsdhjdsjhsdglsdjlljh"
        expected = actual

    Check.QuickThrowOnFailure myProperty
```